# React-Native - I can not use State string as new list element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native, expo

Yesterday I started learning React Native. Unfortunately I encounter some difficulties right at the beggining.
I was trying to write simple list, which contains some input, and when user clicks "Add new" button, list will extend with new item. When I am trying to use this.state.newName variable in a new list element React is throwing me exception:

> " Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found:
>   object with keys {dispatchConfig, _targetInst, isDefaultPrevented,
>   isPropagationStopped, _dispatchListeners, _dispatchInstances, type,
>   target, currentTarget, eventPhase, bubbles, cancelable, timeStamp,
>   defaultPrevented, isTrusted, nativeEvent}). If you meant to render a
>   collection of children, use an array instead."

My code is really simple:

```
export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        newName: "",
        peopleList: [
            { key: "1", name: "Jonathan", lastname: "Smith" },
            { key: "2", name: "Tomasz", lastname: "Kowalski" },
            { key: "2", name: "Adrian", lastname: "Jakubowski" },
        ]

    }
}

addNew() {
    let newName = this.state.newName;
    this.setState({
         peopleList: [...this.state.peopleList, {key: newName, name: newName, lastname: "Added"}]
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.peopleList}>
            <Text>People I know:</Text>
            <TextInput
                value={this.state.newName}
                onChange={(text) => this.setState({newName: text})}
            />
            <Button title="Add new!" 
                onPress={() => this.addNew()}
            />
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.peopleList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.item}>Imie: {item.name} Nazwisko: {item.lastname}</Text>} />

        </View>
    );
}
```

}

When I am not using this.state.newName, and just pass some string like:

```
let newName = "Adam";
```

It will works just fine. What can be a cause?

Comment: `onChange={(text) => this.setState({newName: text})}`
should be: `onChangeText={(newName) => this.setState({ newName })}`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice that problem is not related to a list..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
onChange={(text) => this.setState({newName: text})}
```

To:

```
onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({newName: text})}
```

The right prop is `onChangeText`

You can see the usage of it in [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput)